# ListView only gets first row of .csv file

Tags: c#, listview, csv

I have an excel table with multiple rows, and when I import my .csv file it only displays the first row.
What I want is to fill the list with every row.
cargarCSV() = load .csv file
validar() = pass the csv file to the listview

```
        private void cargarCSV() //Load .csv
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialogoCargar = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialogoCargar.Filter = "Archivos CSV|*.csv";
        dialogoCargar.FilterIndex = 1;
        if(dialogoCargar.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filepath = dialogoCargar.FileName;
            txtbox_ArchivoCargado.Text = filepath;
        }
    }

        private void Validar() //Pass .csv to ListView
    {
        empleadosValido = true;
        try {
            FileStream fileStreamNew = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(fileStreamNew);
            string strView = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            streamRead.Close();
            fileStreamNew.Close();
            String[] strArray = strView.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(strArray[0].ToString());

            item.SubItems.Add(strArray[1].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(strArray[2].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(strArray[3].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(strArray[4].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(strArray[5].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(strArray[6].ToString());

            list_Previ.Items.Add(item);
             }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El archivo se encuentra en uso por otro                    programa\nPor favor cierra otros programas e intenta de nuevo.", "Corporativo  Acosta | Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                empleadosError = true;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            if (ex is IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hay un problema con tus columnas.\nVerifica que correspondan las columnas a importar\ncon las de la tabla (7 columnas)", "Corporativo Acosta | Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK ,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                empleadosError = true;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Split it first with new lines then for each line split it with comma's. That's your problem. But make sure the csv will never contain escaped commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing too much of your actual code, but insering a loop for each line present in your file you should go for

```
foreach(string strView = File.ReadLines(filepath))
{
    String[] strArray = strView.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(strArray[0].ToString());

    item.SubItems.Add(strArray[1].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(strArray[2].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(strArray[3].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(strArray[4].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(strArray[5].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(strArray[6].ToString());
    list_Previ.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Of course you could remove all of your references to the FileStream and StreamReader variables.

Also, if you forecast that some of your lines contains less than 7 elements, I suggest to add a check for the array length just before adding the element to the ListView Items collection and do not rely on exception handling to continue. Using exceptions to drive your code is a bad practice and hitting an exception is costly in terms of performance ( a lot more than putting an if before adding the elements), so something like this should considered

```
if(strArray.Length > 1) item.SubItems.Add(strArray[1].ToString());
if(strArray.Length > 2) item.SubItems.Add(strArray[2].ToString());
....
```